# Reduce float size to fit page

Tags: tables, floats, fontsize, scaling, geometry

I've got a longish sidewaystable which currently is to large for its page. At least with `\footnotesize` it is. With `\scriptsize` it becomes too small, which looks strange and is hard to read.

**Is there some way to (semi-)automatically scale a table to best fit the page?**

I'm thinking about some package which iteratively adjusts font sizes, or which does a magnification of a single box, or some such. Lacking an automated solution, what's the best way to adjust font sizes to a without too much trouble? I'd like to keep the header unscaled, and the caption as well if possible.

Comment: Normally I recommend using font size commands rather than scaling but you can use `\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\begin{tabular...`

Comment: Maybe you can find a decent way to subdivide the data you want to present into two tables?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. Nice except for the fact that I'm currently (ab)using ``\catcode`-=13\def-{$\dotdiv$}`` nested as `\begingroup\catc…\begin{table}…\end{table}\endgroup`. Plugging all of that into a `\resizebox` gives me some error about `\inaccessible`. Seems the change is not local enough. If everything else fails, I'll use a mass search and replace to avoid this redefinition of `-`, but that would make my code less readable than it is now. Not sure how I feel about that.

Comment: @LostBrit: Valid point. On the other hand, it's only one or two lines of the table which won't fit, and using `\scriptsize` is appropriate for the (non-)importance of the data in this table. I have mixed feeling about using yet another page on this data, particularly as the resulting pages would seem rather empty since I can't make the font much larger due to the number and width of the columns I need.

Comment: @MvG (a) abuse is wrong but (b) you just need to put the catcode chages before the resizebox not inside it. (which you want anyway as you don't want to put the `table`  environment into the `\resizebox` (also you don't need/shouldn't use `\begingroup` there just put the catcode changes inside the `table` environment..

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I mistyped my comment, it's `tabular` inside the group not `table`. Moving the catcode change outside the box does work, and I think I might even have an idea as to why this is the case. Do you want to post `\resizebox` as an answer? I'll wait a bit whether someone does have an automated solution, but it looks likely that this might be the most appropriate solution here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
\begin{table}%or {sidewaystable}
%\catcode stuffif you must
\noindent
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{...}
...
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```